# Quetion about measurability of conditional exception.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

If $X,Y,Z:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ are random variables, do we have
$$\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X|Y])^2]=\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z])^2]+\mathrm{E}[(\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z]-\mathrm{E}[X|Y])^2]?$$

**Attempt**

(1)
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X|Y])^2] &= \mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z]+\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z]-\mathrm{E}[X|Y])^2]\\
&= \mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z])^2]+\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X|Y])^2]\\
&\phantom{{}={}}+2\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z])(\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z]-\mathrm{E}[X|Y])].
\end{aligned}$$

(2) We only need $\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z])(\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z]-\mathrm{E}[X|Y])]$ to be zero. By the property of conditional exception, I think we have $\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z])(\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z])]=0$. **I don't know whether it is correct, since $\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z]$ is function on product space $\Omega\times\Omega$, but $X$ is on $
\Omega$.**

But i don't know hot to deal with $\mathrm{E}[X|Y]$. Is it measurable with respect to $\sigma(Y,Z)$?

Comment: I think you are mistaking the fact that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y,Z] : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable with the result of the Doob-Dynkin lemma that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y,Z] = g(Y,Z)$ for some $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes. Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first line says $X,Y,Z$ are all defined on $\Omega$. $\Omega\times \Omega$ does not come into the picture at all.

$\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z])(\mathrm{E}[X|Y,Z])]=0$ is correct. In general $E[(X-E(X|\mathcal G))E(X|\mathcal G)]=0$.

$E(X|Y)$ is measurable w.r.t. $\sigma (Y)$ and $\sigma (Y)\subseteq \sigma (Y,Z)$ so $E(X|Y)$ is measurable w.r.t $\sigma (Y,Z)$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you. I have corrected the typo. If you take $\mathcal G=\sigma (Y,Z)$ in my statement you get what OP wants, right?

Comment: Yes, certainly.  In the corrected form, it directly generalizes the preceding equation.  I was just saying that your [pre-correction] equation was still true by virtue of $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X\mid \mathcal{G})] = \mathbb{E}[X]$, but that by itself wasn't general enough to apply directly to OP's problem.  (I originally had said the equation was wrong before I realized it was still true, which is why my comment may have not been terribly clear)